# PIP Camera Effect iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

How to achieve PIP Effect in iOS Swift app. I tried it but results are not accurate in case of placing and movement of internal picture.
Here is my attempt:

```
    @IBOutlet var galleryImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var background: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var behindView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "ph3")
        let maskingImage = UIImage(named: "mask")
        galleryImageView.image = maskImage(image: image!, mask: maskingImage!)
        galleryImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        background.image = UIImage(named: "ph3")?.stackBlur(10)
        let maskingLayer = CALayer()
        maskingLayer.frame = behindView.bounds
        maskingLayer.contents = (galleryImageView.image?.cgImage! as Any)
        behindView.layer.mask = maskingLayer
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureDetected))
        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.galleryImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }
    func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage{
        let imageReference = image.cgImage
        let maskReference = mask.cgImage
        let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference!.width,
                                height: maskReference!.height,
                                bitsPerComponent: maskReference!.bitsPerComponent,
                                bitsPerPixel: maskReference!.bitsPerPixel,
                                bytesPerRow: maskReference!.bytesPerRow,
                                provider: maskReference!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)
        let maskedReference = imageReference!.masking(imageMask!)
        let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage:maskedReference!)
        return maskedImage
    }
```

galleryImageView is the internal imageView

Result should be like:

[image]

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: Yes i have solved it finally :)

Comment: Please give me suggestion.

Comment: For Pip Effects, we have to desgin the mask of pip shapes in photoshop... and then apply that mask onto the uiview.. so that uiview become modify its rect according to mask,,, and then make uiimageview inside masked view and assign the pip shape to uiimageview.

Comment: I complete this, but the problem is occurring while I try to make the final image.

Comment: If i will take screenshot than size of final image will 320*320 in iphone 5 and iphone 4s.

Comment: the size of the image will be according to the uiview rect size.. in iphone 4s and 5 resolution the image size will be around 320. But you can resize(scale up) the screenshot image... But one thing should be noticed that the scalling will lower the quality of image.

Comment: Yes, that's I said. But in original pip Camera app quality is not lower than also size of the final image is 960*960.

Comment: Hi,Could you please suggest me.how you set frame for particular ImageView

Comment: You can set frame of imageView in storyboard or through code like this: pipView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100);

Comment: Hi...I am facing a lot difficulty in implementing pip effects.Almost ,I have implemented every functionality but when I try to add some custom frames and give _behindView frame dynamically ,it doesn't work ...it either goes too far from the pip frame or goes too wide or large due to wrong frame.Please suggest how you give frame to behindview or share some code to help.

Comment: @Mughees can you please share your code.

Comment: Hey Mughees, Can you Provide some code, i am stuck in PIP camera..